# Finding cdf of continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, continuity, random-variables

I am giving the following question:

Consider a random variable, $X$, having pdf: 
     $f_x(x) = (x^2)/3, I(-2,1) (x)$

(a) Give the cdf of $Y = X^2$

I believe the support of $X^2$ is $[0, 4)$, is that correct?

When trying to find the cdf, I look for $P(Y <= X^2) = P(-y^{(1/2)} <= X <= y^{(1/2)})$

I then integrate from $-y^{(1/2)}$ to $y^{(1/2)}$ which gives me $\frac{2}{9}y^{(2/3)}$ which gives me $0$ when I plug in $0$ but I don't get $1$ when I plug in the upper bound support of $4$.

Since the cdf must be bounded by $0$ and $1$, I don't understand why I'm not able to get the correct answer. I've also tried integrating from $-2$ to $-y^{1/2}$ and then from $0$ to $y^{1/2}$ and that doesn't get me the correct answer either.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The initial pdf of the random variable should read (x^2)/3 since you are raising x to the second power and then dividing by 3. Not raising x to the 2/3 power.

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking the 'edit' link that appears under it.

Comment: Thank you, just edited!

Comment: Not sure why this has a close vote. I'll add fancy math font for you. Let me know if anything looks messed up, or you can go into the edit and try to fix it yourself, and learn some formatting in the process. :)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I could do that with the formatting, it looks perfect. This is my first question on here, so I'll definitely take note.

Comment: I wish I knew enough to answer the question! :)

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it by clicking the green arrow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cdf of $X$ is $F_X(x)=\frac{x^3+8}{9}$ for $(-2\le x\le 1)$

$F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(X^2\le y)=P(-\sqrt{y}\le X\le \sqrt{y})=F_X(\sqrt{y})-F_X(-\sqrt{y})$

$=\frac{8+\min(1,y^\frac{3}{2})}{9}-\frac{8-y^\frac{3}{2}}{9}$, since $F_X(x)=1$ for $x\ge 1$.

Summary:
$F_Y(y)=\frac{2y^\frac{3}{2}}{9}$ for $0\le y\le 1$ and 
$F_Y(y)=(\frac{1+y^\frac{3}{2}}{9})$ for $1\lt y\le 4$

Comment: Why are you multiplying $P(X\le \sqrt{y}|X\ge 0)P(X\ge 0)$ together?

Comment: Previous answer was wrong.  I corrected it.

Comment: Note simplification.